# R: Regex to match pattern in square brackets with exception

Tags: r, regex

I have this string:

“[DELW][0x00][BKSP][0x00][0x12][0xE0][0xF0][0xEF][DOWN][UP]asdkjaosdkj[ENTER]”

I want to remove all the keytab (in square bracket) starting with numbers like [0x00], [0xF0].

Final result would be: “[DELW][BKSP][DOWN][UP]asdkjaosdkj[ENTER]”

I thought about using str_replace but having a hard time coming up with regex that works. I would really appreciate all the help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If your stuff to remove is always `0x` and two hex digits then:

```
> gsub("\\[0x..\\]","",s)
[1] "[DELW][BKSP][DOWN][UP]asdkjaosdkj[ENTER]"
```

Note the `\` needed to stop `[]` being special, and the `\\` to get a real backslash into an R string.

If you want to pull in the `stringr` package you can do it with the same pattern:

```
> stringr::str_replace_all(s, "\\[0x..\\]","")
[1] "[DELW][BKSP][DOWN][UP]asdkjaosdkj[ENTER]"
```

But `base::gsub` keeps things light.

Answer (score 0):

**I think you can try this**

```
\[[^0x]+]
```

> Explanation

`\[` - Literally match **[** character.

`[^0x]+` - Match anything one or more time except 0x.

`]` - Literally match **]** character

[image]